# Most accepted way to load a new iOS view without leaving current storyboard

Tags: ios, view, storyboard

I am confused as to Storyboards in iOS. I want to use them and have my code be as modern as possible, but somewhat confused. Here is my problem:

In the main view of my app, you click a button and some time-consuming things happen behind the scenes (music plays, some files are concatenated). While this is happening, I want a menu with some text fields to slide up and let the user enter some info, and then he will click a button to dismiss this menu.

This menu can cover the full screen, but I don't want to segue to a new Storyboard entirely, because there is stuff going on in the background and we'll need to come back to the main view soon.

### One thing I tried was to create a new storyboard for this menu and load it using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, which works, but then I can't dismiss it later without the app crashing. But maybe there is a better way anyway? What is proper programming style on this?

Someone asked about my code, I think this is the only place I can put it? Here it is. In the main view:

```
AddInfoController *infoSheet = [[AddInfoController alloc] init]; //subclass of viewcontroller
infoSheet = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddInfoView"];
[self.view addSubview:infoSheet.view];
```

then in my AddInfoController class I have:

```
- (IBAction)clickedDoneButton:(id)sender {
   [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

and in the AddInfoView storyboard, I have a button which is hooked to that IBAction. When it crashes, nothing appears in NSLog, it shows me some hex stuff in Thread 1 and a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Answer (score 1):

Ok - if you are bent on using Storyboards and the app keeps crashing when you present the dismiss button, there's most certainly an error you are making. The console error message would be helpful. What are you seeing there.

If Storyboards is taking too much of my time, I would do it programmatically and simply present a Modal View. If you haven't tried before, try presenting a view controller modally. You can learn more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

Comment: AddInfoController *infoSheet = [[AddInfoController alloc] init]; // this is a subclass of ViewController

Comment: SORRY I am bad at this. I added my code to the original question/

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and UITextViews programmatically and them to the main view. Try something like this:

```
UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 420)];
    UITextField * someTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 240, 44)]; // create uitextfield or something else as much as you want.
    [someView addSubview:someTextField];
    [someTextField release];
    [self.view addSubview:someView];
    [someView release];
```

And create a action button to dismiss the view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling removeFromParentViewController but you never actually add it as a child. I don't know if that is what is actually calling the crash, but basically the format to use is:

taken from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html):

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
    content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
    [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

Then after you are finished you call the equivalent methods in reverse:

```
- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
   [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
   [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
   [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

Comment: Also, a crash log would be helpful to figure out where the crash comes from